# Sum of quantity column based on the grouped of product_id column values with their respective names form name column

Tags: sql

Here is what my table looks like:

[image: Here is what my table looks like]

Here what I need:

[image: Here what I need]

I tried this code

```
SELECT DISTINCT(product_id), 
    SUM(quantity) OVER (PARTITION BY product_id) AS sumquantity     
FROM ord1;
```

Comment: is there a reason you're not using `group by`?

Comment: GROUP BY is your friend in this case ;) For someone to give you the full SQL statement you should include the actual column names in your pictures.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GROUP BY will do the trick in this case!

```
SELECT emp, name, product, SUM(quantity) 
FROM ord1
GROUP BY emp, name, product
ORDER BY emp, name, product
```

Replace the column names with the ones from your database table.

Comment: thanks for your reply   i replace column names but i didnt get the result as what i expect

Comment: this is wat i get after updating the query https://ibb.co/F3XH9mB

Comment: You need to understand how grouping works, as soon as you introduce the order_id you are destroying the grouping, leave out order_id and you will get the result from the image of the result you wanted.

Comment: If you want the total sum of quantity based on the customer and product id you have to leave out the order_id as it's going to mess up the logic.

Comment: i tried removing that but still dint got result as a expected  https://ibb.co/LSpPfbD

Comment: Sorry! My bad, see my updated answer ;) Quantity should of course not be a part of the GROUP BY clause

Comment: after removing quantity from group clause i am getting this result  https://ibb.co/r2kVH4R

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what you asked for ;) Grouped by customer, then the product with the sum of that product. What is wrong with that?

Comment: If you want it sorted differently just add ORDER BY CUST_NAME, PRODUCT_ID

Comment: ya correct thanks i cofused with names now clear thank you very much

Comment: Happy to help out :) Please mark the answer as the correct answer to help a low reputation guy out :D